# Aggregating Dataset to "ignore" categorical variable

Tags: r, dataset, aggregation, categorical-data

I have this dataset wich is structured like this

```
Neighborhood,  var1,   var2,   COUNTRY, DAY, categ 1, categ 2
     1          700     724      AL      0      YES    YES
     1          500     200      FR      0      YES     NO
    ....
     1          701     659      IT      1      NO      YES
     1          791     669      IT      1      NO      YES
    ....
     2          239     222      GE      0      YES      NO
```

and so on...

So that the hyerarchy is "Neighborhood > DAY > COUNTRY" and for every neighborhood,for every day, for every country I have the observation of var1,var2,categ1 and categ2

I'm not interested for the moment in analyzing the country, so what I want to do is to aggregate that (by summing "over" the country field var1 and var2, the categorical variables categ1 and categ2 are not influenced by the country), and have a dataset that for each Neighborhood and for each Day gives me the infos on var1, var2, categ1 and categ2

I'm quite new to R-programming and basically don't know a lot of packages (I would write a program in c++, but I'm forcing myself to learn R)...
So do you have any idea on how to do this?

Data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Neighborhood = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L),
                      var1 = c(700L, 500L, 701L, 791L, 239L),
                      var2 = c(724L, 200L, 659L, 669L, 222L),
                      COUNTRY = c("AL", "FR", "IT", "IT", "GE"),
                      DAY = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L),
                      `categ 1` = c("YES", "YES", "NO", "NO", "YES"), 
                      `categ 2` = c("YES", "NO", "YES", "YES", "NO")),
                 .Names = c("Neighborhood", "var1", "var2", "COUNTRY", "DAY", "categ 1", "categ 2"),
                 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

EDIT: @akrun

when I try your command,  the result is:

aggregate(.~Neighborhood+DAY+COUNTRY, data= df1[!grepl("^categ", names(df1))], mean)

```
     Neighborhood, DAY, COUNTRY, var1, var2

1            1      0      AL     700  724
2            1      0      FR     500  200
3            2      0      GE     239  222
4            1      1      IT     746  664
```

But (in this example) what I would like to have is:

```
         Neighborhood, DAY,  var1, var2

1            1          0     1200  924           //wher var1=700+500....
2            1          1     1492  1328
3            2          0     239  222
```

Comment: Do you want `aggregate(.~Neighbourhood+DAY+COUNTRY, data= df1[!grepl("^categ, names(df1))], mean)`

Comment: no I'm interested in the categ columns, i'm not interested in the country column...
so following your example I should do:
aggregate(.~Neighbourhood+DAY, data= df1[!grepl("^COUNTRY, names(df1))], sum)
right?

Comment: No, that will not work.  If you are interested in the categ columns, are those included in the grouping columns?

Comment: the categorical variables are only grouping days and neighborhoods, so it should be fine to remove them before the aggregation and add them later?

Comment: Please check the solution.  It does that.

Comment: @akrun I edited the question, I think it should be more clear now! thank you very much

Comment: The `1 1` values should be `1492 1328`

Comment: Just saw the edit to your answer, it's what I meant! thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are not interested in the 'categ' columns, we can `grep` them out and use `aggregate`

```
aggregate(.~Neighborhood+DAY, data= df1[!grepl("^(categ|COUNTRY)", names(df1))], sum)
#   Neighborhood DAY var1 var2
#1            1   0 1200  924
#2            2   0  239  222
#3            1   1 1492 1328
```

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(Neighborhood, DAY) %>%
   summarise_each(funs(sum), matches("^var"))
#  Neighborhood   DAY  var1  var2
#         (int) (int) (int) (int)
#1            1     0  1200   924
#2            1     1  1492  1328
#3            2     0   239   222
```

Comment: what about `aggregate(cbind(var1, var2) ~ COUNTRY, df1, mean)`